# Want to redirect after to other page after MySQL insert

Tags: php

This is my PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

 
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "pass1") or die ('error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test2");
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO test2 values (NULL, '$name', 
'$pass');";
 
mysql_query($sql) or die ('error: ' . mysql_error());

if $post('index2.php');
?>
```

Here I just want to redirect to other page after I submit my form, my form is just sample

With row input by the name of name and pass that's all

Comment: `if $post('index2.php');` ? what this line do in your code ? variables can't take parameters

Comment: was just for explaining quistion, dear

Answer (score 4):

Try this before you write anything to the HTTP body:

`header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`

Comment: but if i do that there will be direct, redirection i want to insert my data to mysql and redirect to other page

Comment: No problem, then. The only time an issue comes up is when you do something like print text or another action that will fill data into the HTTP body. Just inserting data into MySQL won't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result ==1 ) {
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit();
}
```

Comment: have try but not help,

Comment: no error just takes me direct to the example page i dont' see my form

Comment: hey you have to put your form page url instead of example.com

Comment: Did you check the database .. is your entry inserted in DB ?

Comment: it's like that, i have form and i want when i insert to the form and submite it should redirect me to other page not stay here.

Comment: on which page you want to redirect after insertion?

Comment: on form, after i insert the form so it shoudl redirect me after inserting i have all one page my form and php are in same page

Comment: you can reload(refresh) your page after insertion if you have all code in same page

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
<?php

//DB settings and connection keep it in a separate file and include it here.
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "pass1") or die ('error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test2");


if($_POST["submit"]){
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $pass = $_POST['pass'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO test2 values (NULL, '$name', '$pass');";
     mysql_query($sql) or die ('error: ' . mysql_error());

     header("location:your_next_page.php");

}


?>
```

Note : mysql_* functiona are deprecated use mysqli_* functions OR PDO

Comment: In this line : `if($_POST["submit"]){` `submit` is the name of the submit tag in your html form and `header("location:your_next_page.php")` is the page wer you redirect

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to redirect the user **if** the query executes successfully. Use an `if` condition like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test2 values (NULL, '$name', '$pass');";
$var = mysql_query($sql) or die ('error: ' . mysql_error()); //insert data
if($var){
header('Location: http://www.example.com/foo/bar/'); //redirect
}
else{
echo "Query failed";
}
```

Comment: it's not leting me to enter any thing just when i load the page take me to the expample one

Comment: Then it means the query executed successfully. Is that not what you want?

Comment: no i want it shoud first show my form and when i inter data and submite then it should redirect me to other page not stay on this form

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
     $sql = "INSERT INTO test2 values (NULL, '$name', '$pass');";
     mysql_query($sql) or die ('error: ' . mysql_error());

     header("location:your_next_page.php");
}
```

This will redirect only after the form was submitted and after you inserted your data to db.

Answer (score 0):

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
```

Comment: i want first insert to mysql the data, after that i should redirect me when i click on submit the data go to database and also redirect me to other page.  this will take me just as open the page